# phpMyAdmin - foreign key not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I am working to establish a foreign key relationship between two tables in phpMyAdmin on my cPanel server - I'll just call them 'parent' and 'child' to keep things simple.  In the child table, I have a parent_id column which I want to populate with the id numbers from the parent table.  I have followed a few tutorials on this, but it just doesn't seem to be working - new records are created, but the parent_id column on the child table remains NULL.

My html form data is passed to PHP which inserts the data into two separate tables, parent and child, in the same action.  The parent and child tables are essentially duplicates, but in the future I will likely be adding additional child tables, hence the need for the foreign key relationship - basically a master table with unconnected local tables.

In phpMyAdmin, I set the storage engine for both parent and child tables to InnoDB.  In the child table, I added a parent_id column, set the default to NULL, and allowed for NULL.  I then indexed that column, and set the foreign key constraint to 'parent'.'ID'. phpMyAdmin automatically generated a constraint name, 'child_ibfk_1'. ON DELETE and ON UPDATE are both set to cascade.

When I create a new record, both tables are populated correctly, but the parent_id column in the child table is NULL rather than the ID of the parent.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? Thanks very much.

Edit - php insert statements:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO parent (date, time, latitude, longitude, accuracy, species, deadinjured, sex, age, name, contact_info, notes, source)
VALUES ('$date', '$time', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$accuracy', '$species', '$deadinjured', '$sex', '$age', '$name', '$contact_info', '$notes', 'source 1');";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO child (date, time, latitude, longitude, accuracy, species, deadinjured, sex, age, name, contact_info, notes)
VALUES ('$date', '$time', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$accuracy', '$species', '$deadinjured', '$sex', '$age', '$name', '$contact_info', '$notes');";
```

Comment: `When I create a new record, both tables are populated correctly` -- Can we see the exact query/queries you're executing?

Comment: Coming right up - I'll edit them into my original question.

Comment: You have to explicitly provide the parent ID in the `INSERT` command that inserts into the child table.  You can get the parent record's ID immediately after it has been inserted by using the API's relevant function: e.g. [`mysql_insert_id()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php), [`mysqli::$insert_id`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php), [`PDO::lastInsertId`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) etc.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is definitely the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you need to manually link your `child` record with its associated record in the `parent` table, by *explicitly* setting the value of `child.parent_id`.  Your foreign key constraint only serves to enforce a rule that says "when a value is added to `child.parent_id`, it needs to match a value in `parent.id`."

Further, your `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` cascades will only work after you've set the value of `child.parent_id`.

Comment: Ah, I understand!  Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem!  And as eggyal described, you can easily fetch the new value of `parent.id` so that you can then insert it into `child.parent_id`.

Comment: Yep, you guys nailed it.